# Replace multiline string in all files in terminal

Tags: regex, perl, terminal

I have a couple of files in a directory, in which I have a piece of text between two separators.

```
Text to keep

//###==###
Text to remove
//###==###

Text to keep
```

After an extensive search, I found the following Mac OS X Terminal command, with which I can remove the separators themselves.

```
perl -pi -w -e 's|//###==###||g' `find . -type f`
```

However, I need something with a regex that does not only remove the separators themselves, but also what is in between. Something like this, although this line doesn't do anything.

```
perl -pi -w -e 's|//###==###(.*)//###==###||g' `find . -type f`
```

**EDIT AFTER DUPLICATE FLAG**

I see something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146745/how-should-i-use-perls-scalar-range-operator), using the scalar range operator, but I cannot make it work for me. Failed attempts include:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's|//###==###..//###==###||g' `find . -type f`
perl -pi -w -e 's|//###==###(..)//###==###||g' `find . -type f`
perl -pi -w -e 's|//###==###[..]//###==###||g' `find . -type f`
```

**SOLUTION**

With the help of dawg below, the following oneliner will do exactly what I want:

```
$ perl -0777 -p -i -e 's/(^\s*^\/\/###==###.*?\/\/###==###\s*)//gms' `find . -type f -name "index.php"`
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2147588/223226

Comment: Are you not getting this error: `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`?

Comment: `perl -ne 'print unless m|//###==###| ... m|//###==###|'`

Comment: @RobEarl's comment should be an answer.  That's how the range operator's used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
s/(^\s*^\/\/###==###.*?\/\/###==###\s*)//gms
```

[Working Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dP1yM9/1)

Then in the terminal and in Perl. Given:

```
$ echo "$tgt"
Text to keep

//###==###
Text to remove
//###==###

Text to keep
```

Use the `-0777` command flag to slurp the whole file and then:

```
$ echo "$tgt" | perl -0777 -ple 's/(^\s*^\/\/###==###.*?\/\/###==###\s*)//gms'
Text to keep
Text to keep
```

Or, you can use the range operator. If done this way, you cannot remove the leading and trailing blank lines if that is your intent:

```
$ echo "$tgt" | perl -lne 'print unless (/\/\/###==###/ ... /\/\/###==###/)'
Text to keep


Text to keep
```

Comment: Thanks! :-) The option with -0777 seems to work fine. Is there a way to perform this on all files, and save the files in the same action?

Comment: This seems to work for that (font looks weird due to conflict os meaning of the apostrophe): $ perl -0777 -p -i -e 's/(^\s*^\/\/###==###.*?\/\/###==###\s*)//gms' `find . -type f -name "index.php"`